# Disable click on anchor if form is invalid

Tags: angularjs

I've tried several solutions on other answers but so far none has worked as needed, basically I need to disable a button (anchor) if the form is invalid, disabling is not the problem, avoiding the call to the function is.

For that I tried something like this:

```
<a class="btn icon-btn btn-success" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" novalidate ng-submit="myForm.$valid && submit.addOrEditItem()">
<span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-save img-circle text-success"></span>Save</a>
```

And on my controller:

```
    $scope.isCreating = true;

    $scope.submit = {
        addOrEdit: function() {

        if($scope.isCreating){
            $scope.items.push({type: $scope.newItem.name, description: $scope.newItem.descriptions, isDone:false, editable:false});

        }else{

            $scope.eItem.type         = $scope.newItem.name;
            $scope.eItem.description  = $scope.newItem.descriptions;
        }


            $scope.isCreating = true;
            $scope.newItem = {};
        }
    }
```

Is there any alternatives for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ng-submit, use ng-click:

```
<a class="btn icon-btn btn-success" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" novalidate ng-click="myForm.$valid && submit.addOrEdit()">
```

Comment: @CodeGrasshopper, maybe it was because You had your function call as submit.addOrEditItem, when the correct function name was submit.addOrEdit.